# Java: Convert HEX byte array to 16 fixed length binary String

Tags: java, arrays, binary, hex, byte

I have a byte array obtained by automatically MYBATIS conversion.
Into ORACLE DB column (RAW type) I have HEX value (example: 0x0, 0x81, 0xC801).
This value is stored with maximum 2 bytes (example 1100100000000001 -> 0xC801, 0000000000000000 -> 0x0)

I have a problem when i read and convert this value.

I need to convert the byte array obtained by automatically conversion, to 16 fixed length binary string.

For example if the value in DB is **0x0**:

- byte array is [0] (automatically MYBATIS conversion)
- binary string that I need must be 0000000000000000

For example if the value in DB is **0xC801**:

- byte array is [0, -56, 1] (automatically MYBATIS conversion)
- binary string that I need must be 1100100000000001

How i can do that?

I tried with this solution but doesn't work with HEX value like 0x0 or 0x81 because 0x0 is mapped to "0" and 0x81 is mapped to "100000001". 0 padding is missing... and i don't know how to add the padding insite this script.

```
private static final char[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

public static String bytesToBinary(byte[] bytes) {
    return hexToBin(bytesToHex(bytes));
}

public static String hexToBin(String s) {

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(s)) {
        return new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2);
    }

    return "";
}

public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {

    if (bytes != null && bytes.length > 0) {

        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];

        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
        }

        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: Do you always want to convert just two bytes.  Are you always returned a 3 byte array?

Comment: @WJS Read the question again. *"byte array is [0]"* and *"byte array is [0, -56, 1]"*. Question has 2 examples, of length 1 and 3, respectively, so no, it is not always just two bytes.

Comment: @Andreas The title says convert to a 16 bit string.  That implies 2 bytes to me.

Comment: @WJS Yes, and the question text shows 2 examples of byte arrays with 1 and 3 bytes. Since the first byte is 0, that is still at most a 16 bit value.

Comment: Which is what I said.  You only want to convert at most two bytes (in spite of the array size).

Comment: @WJS But that is not what you asked. Maybe a better phrasing of that comment would make it clearer what you were trying to ask, because the example with input `[0]` is a 1-byte array, which means the answer to your question, as it's currently phrased, is "no", i.e. "not always two bytes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `BigInteger`

```
byte[] bytes = {0, -56, 1};
        
                              // array, offset, length 
String result = new BigInteger(bytes).setBit(16).toString(2).substring(1);
System.out.println(result);
```

Prints

```
1100100000000001
```

Comment: Close, but with input `{0}` the output is `0`, not the requested `0000000000000000`. Can be fixed e.g. as follows: `new BigInteger(bytes).setBit(16).toString(2).substring(1)`

Comment: If you use `new BigInteger(bytes)` instead of `new BigInteger(bytes,0,3)`, then the code can handle any byte array of length 1-4, instead of only handling arrays of length 3.

Comment: Also, the `BigInteger​(byte[] val, int off, int len)` constructor wasn't even added until Java 9, so by changing to the `BigInteger​(byte[] val)` constructor it'll work for all Java versions *(well, Java 1.1+)*.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! SOLVED with your solution :)